# What’s the point of desaturation and equalization in face detection?

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection

When I play the face detection code, I get some confusion. When I comment these two sentences:

```
//cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
//equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );
```

the result is still the same, which means Opencv (detectMultiScale) can still successfully find people’s face. I am thinking that what’s the point of changing colour-image to gray-image, and then getting the histogram of the gray-image?

I attach part of the code as follows:

```
while (cvWaitKey(10) < 0)
{
Mat frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); // get the next frame of video
cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray ); 
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) ); // Detect faces
for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ ) // for each face found
{
Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 ); // location of this face
ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 ); // draw ellipse around this face}
imshow( "faces", frame);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

OR:

```
while (cvWaitKey(10) < 0)
{
Mat frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); // get the next frame of video
//cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
//equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray ); 
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) ); // Detect faces
for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ ) // for each face found
{
Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 ); // location of this face
ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 ); // draw ellipse around this face}
imshow( "faces", frame);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: You might get better responses if you tag your question appropriately with the library/api/platform you are using here. If you're using the OpenCV library, tag your question with that.

Comment: For clarification, please indent your code correctly - it will make it easier for people to answer your question. I would suggest the edits myself, but I'm not sure about whether the `}` at the end of the "draw ellipse..." comment should be on a new line. Also it will improve visibility of your question if you tag it with both language and the particular detection framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The point of desaturation is to reduce the amount of data, since the algorithm works without color. The point of equalization is to compensate for lighting variations.

You can find more information here: [Face Recognition using OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition)